# Flex 4.6 Mobile - how to know which itemrenderer is visible

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have a sparks List with the following attributes:

```
    verticalScrollPolicy="off" 
    horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
    pageScrollingEnabled="true"
    scrollSnappingMode="leadingEdge"
```

and inside is an ItemRenderer that takes up a full screen for each item. So basically it is a horizontal list that lets you swipe left and right one page at a time. Note the scrollSnappingMode is on, so the pages always snap perfectly on the page.

Also, I am setting "useVirtualLayout=true" on the Layout, so I have virtual ItemRenderers that are getting recycled.

My question is this: how do I know which ItemRenderer is currently on the screen? Is there an event or property to watch that lets me know when this page has snapped into view and is the currently visible page?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I know which ItemRenderer is currently on the screen?

In the situation you describe, which uses Virtual Layouts and only one element displayed on screen at a time; there will only be a single itemRenderer.

You can access the dataProvider element of the itemRenderer using the data property on your itemRenderer.

You can find the index of your data in the dataProvider using the [itemIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IItemRenderer.html#itemIndex) property on the itemRenderer.

If you want to know when the list changes from the component that contains the list; you may try listening to the change event; but I'm not sure if that will give you want you need; as it is possible to scroll without selecting a new item.

Comment: that's not quite true, there's definitely more than one ItemRenderer at a time. If I just swipe a little bit in either direction without changing page I can see two items side by side. So there's at least two renderers at a time, but I think more probably it's three because it creates one to the left and to the right of the current one. So the question remains: which one is the visible one?

Comment: In the MX List they had a property, offscreenExtraRowsorColumns that were used strictly for this purpose.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#offscreenExtraRowsOrColumns It seems likely that the Spark lists have something similar. Possibly on the layout or DataGroup?  Nothing is obvious to me.  Why does it matter which renderer is visible?

Comment: It's important to me because for a number reasons I would like to keep track of which page the user is currently on. Is there a way to see the absolute X and Y positioning of an ItemRenderer? That way when both are at zero then I know that it is being currently displayed on screen....

Comment: The page analogy does not work well in an Applications; so when you talk of "page" it is very confusing to me what you're after.  Read info about the Flex Coordinate system here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7de0.html Assuming that "Absolute" refers to the global coordinates; you probably want to use localToGlobal() to convert the X & Y position of he itemRenderer to the X and Y Position relative to the top level application.